# How to convert an output of "by" function to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, apply

Here is what I want to Do:
I have a dataframe df defined as:

```
col1 <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b")
col2 <- c("z","z","x","x","z","x", "z","z","x","x","z","x")
col3 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
```

and a function pred that calculates the mean defined as :

```
pred <- function(subset_df){return(mean(subset_df$col3))}
```

I want a data frame through a by function in a below format:

```
col1 col2 col3_mean
a     x    4.33
a     z    2.66
b     x    10.33
b     z    8.66
```

I am currently using a by() function to partition this data into its strata and apply a pred() function that calculates a mean

```
by_keys <- c("col1","col2")
data_sub <- by(df, data_sub[,by_keys], pred)  
data_sub <- do.call(rbind, data_sub)
```

I am getting an error here saying the "Error in do.call(rbind, data_sub) : second argument must be a list"

I tried a solution from a similar tread but I dont get col1 and col2 as in desired format

```
as.data.frame(vapply(data_sub,unlist,unlist(data_sub[[1]])))
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This is easily done by `aggregate(col3~.,df,mean)`

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `by` as you set up will not return a list but a simplified structure since your output returns numeric vectors. Adjust your *pred* function to return data frames which being non-simplified structures will force `by` to return a list and can then be passed into `do.call`.

```
pred <- function(subset_df){    
  df <- data.frame(col1 = subset_df$col1[[1]], 
                   col2 = subset_df$col2[[1]],
                   col3_mean = mean(subset_df$col3)
                  )                      
  return(df)
}

data_sub_list <- by(df, df[,by_keys], pred)  
data_sub <- do.call(rbind, data_sub_list)
data_sub

#   col1 col2 col3_mean
# 1    a    x  4.333333
# 2    b    x 10.333333
# 3    a    z  2.666667
# 4    b    z  8.666667
```

---

However, as commented by @Onyambu, this type of grouped aggregation can be done with `aggregate` which will return data frames.

```
# FORMULA VERSION
aggregate(col3 ~ col1 + col2, df, mean)
#   col1 col2 col3_mean
# 1    a    x  4.333333
# 2    b    x 10.333333
# 3    a    z  2.666667
# 4    b    z  8.666667

# NON-FORMULA VERSION
aggregate(df$col3, by=list(col1=df$col1, col2=df$col2), mean)
#   col1 col2         x
# 1    a    x  4.333333
# 2    b    x 10.333333
# 3    a    z  2.666667
# 4    b    z  8.666667
```

---

Usually, `by` (being the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) is best for running larger, extensive data frame operations that you need to run subsets through iteratievly. In fact, if you need multiple aggregates, `by` then becomes useful:

```
pred <- function(subset_df){      
  df <- data.frame(col1 = subset_df$col1[[1]], 
                   col2 = subset_df$col2[[1]],
                   col3_mean = mean(subset_df$col3),
                   col3_sd = sd(subset_df$col3),
                   col3_median = median(subset_df$col3),
                   col3_min = min(subset_df$col3),
                   col3_max = max(subset_df$col3),
                   col3_sum = sum(subset_df$col3),
                   col3_25pct = quantile(subset_df$col3)[[2]],
                   col3_75pct = quantile(subset_df$col3)[[4]],
                   col3_IQR = IQR(subset_df$col3)
                  )      
  return(df)
}

data_sub_list <- by(df, df[,by_keys], pred)  
data_sub <- do.call(rbind, data_sub_list)

#   col1 col2 col3_mean  col3_sd col3_median col3_min col3_max col3_sum col3_25pct col3_75pct col3_IQR
# 1    a    x  4.333333 1.527525           4        3        6       13        3.5        5.0      1.5
# 2    b    x 10.333333 1.527525          10        9       12       31        9.5       11.0      1.5
# 3    a    z  2.666667 2.081666           2        1        5        8        1.5        3.5      2.0
# 4    b    z  8.666667 2.081666           8        7       11       26        7.5        9.5      2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  summarize(col3_mean = mean(col3)) %>%
  as.data.frame


  col1 col2 col3_mean
1    a    x     4.333
2    a    z     2.667
3    b    x    10.333
4    b    z     8.667
```